# Report Definition (RDL) Hide In Tile View

Tags: reporting-services, rdl

I have some subreports which I would like to have hidden from the tile view in SSRS when they're deployed.

Is there a way to have the .rdl specify this or is this particular property only available through the SSRS interface?

Comment: What do you mean by "tile view"? Can you edit your question, and be more specific as well as tell us what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Whether a report is hidden or visible in Report Manager is not a property of the .rdl / report itself, and can only be set once the report is uploaded to the SSRS server.

Answer (score 1):

You can set this property directly from the sql reporting server:

```
Update [ReportServer].[dbo].[Catalog]
  Set Hidden = 1
  Where <condition>
```